# working with "load more" button using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I was working on ratemyprofessor which has a load more button to load more professor, and I use debugger to analyze network, it shows up a js request. 
[ratemyprofessorwebsite](https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/campusRatings.jsp?sid=1273)

I was thinking, for the request URL, there is a start and rows, so I just increase the start by 20 each time, will this work?

And someone told me that I could try formdata, but in this case, there is no formdata and it is not a POST method, am I right?

I am really new to scrapy and python, hope u guys can give me some insight. Really appreciate it

they don't allow me to upload image... but anyway

```
Request URL:https://search-a.akamaihd.net/typeahead/suggest/?solrformat=true&rows=10&callback=noCB&q=*%3A*+AND+schoolid_s%3A1273&defType=edismax&qf=teacherfullname_t%5E1000+autosuggest&bf=pow(total_number_of_ratings_i%2C2.1)&sort=total_number_of_ratings_i+desc&siteName=rmp&rows=20&start=20&fl=pk_id+teacherfirstname_t+teacherlastname_t+total_number_of_ratings_i+averageratingscore_rf+schoolid_s
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:23.212.53.206:443
```

QUERY STING PARAMETERS

```
solrformat:true
rows:10
callback:noCB
q:*:* AND schoolid_s:1273
defType:edismax
qf:teacherfullname_t^1000 autosuggest
bf:pow(total_number_of_ratings_i,2.1)
sort:total_number_of_ratings_i desc
siteName:rmp
rows:20
start:20
fl:pk_id teacherfirstname_t teacherlastname_t total_number_of_ratings_iaverageratingscore_rf schoolid_s
```

Comment: "load more": link can load data inside the page in many ways, it can be POST request with Simple HTML response object or JSON response object or it can be GET method will HTML/JSON response, open your firefox(i would use that) and monitor network call

Comment: your next step would highly depend on what type of call is being made to collect next data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct - formdata is not required, and this is straight forward using GET method calls.

using the following parameters, grab the json response with:

```
data = json.loads(response.body)
records = data['response']['docs']
```

---

parameters to use : **start, rows**

parameter to avoid : **callback**

parameters with explanation:

```
solrformat:true
#callback:noCB # Drop this parameter, this will give you response data in json format
q:*:* AND schoolid_s:1273
defType:edismax
qf:teacherfullname_t^1000 autosuggest
bf:pow(total_number_of_ratings_i,2.1)
sort:total_number_of_ratings_i desc
siteName:rmp
rows:20 
# rows: the amount of records you want in a single response, this will give you 20
# you can try with maximum that can be returned in single response i.e 500, 1000..etc, this will minimize no of request made to website 
start:20  
#start :you can start this from 0,10,20,30,40 manually as well if you know the total number of records.
fl:pk_id teacherfirstname_t teacherlastname_t total_number_of_ratings_iaverageratingscore_rf schoolid_s
```

Comment: what is response.body in this persons case?